# Prevent overwriting errors message on a page

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-5.4

I have a page with 2 separated forms, routes and requests.

In this forms I have a field with the same name (for example in each form I have `email` field).

The problem is when I validating one forms and when form have error, in both forms the error will show.

How can I prevent overwriting errors ?

This is my codes:

**Register Request :**

```
class RegisterFormRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
            'name' => 'required',
            'location' => 'required'
        ];
    }
}
```

**Login Request:**

```
class LoginFormRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required'
        ];
    }
}
```

in blade I use this code above of email field in both forms:

```
{{$errors->has('email') ? 'has-error' : null }}
```

When I don't enter email in Login form and submit, the error will show above of email field in Register form too.

Comment: Maybe you can just change the name of the field email to something else?

Comment: @MozammilKhodabacchas Thanks, but because the field name is the same as my column in database, I cannot change the field name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found the solution.

I should add `$errorBag` variable in `Request` file:

```
class RegisterFormRequest extends FormRequest
{
    protected $errorBag = 'register';

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
            'name' => 'required',
            'location' => 'required'
        ];
    }
}
```

and in blade:

```
{{$errors->register->has('email') ? 'has-error' : null }}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution but I am not sure if it is the best way of doing it. The login controller uses the `AuthenticatesUsers` trait which contains a method `sendFailedLoginResponse`

By overriding this method in `LoginController`, you can name the error message bag like this:

```
protected function sendFailedLoginResponse(Request $request)
{
    $errors = [$this->username() => trans('auth.failed')];

    if ($request->expectsJson()) {
        return response()->json($errors, 422);
    }

    return redirect()->back()
        ->withInput($request->only($this->username(), 'remember'))
        ->withErrors($errors, 'login');
}
```

Then, in your blade file you can maybe do something like this:

```
@if (! $errors->login->isEmpty())
    <ul>
        @foreach ($errors->login->all() as $error)
            <li>{{ $error }}</li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
@endif
```

Comment: Thanks but I use `Request` and not validate in controller